# How to recover spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, data-recovery

I have tried restoring the spreadsheet from the version history. But still, I am unable to restore the data. I update the sheet every day, it has been updated until a day before yesterday completely. but not now when I have opened the sheet, the data is missing for last few days, and restore from version history didn't help.